# How do you find odd positive integers with python [no loops style]?

Tags: python

The problem I'm trying to solve is rather simple: write a function `q2(n)` that would return `n` odd positive integers. For example, `q2(3)` should return `[1,3,5]`.

I have solved it, as you can see in the code below, using a `for` loop. However, there was a note to the problem that said 'try to not use loops'. So the question is: **how do I do that without using loops?**

Here's my version:

```
def q2(n):
    num100 = list(range(100))
    odd = []

    for i in num100:
        if (i%2) != 0:
            odd.append(i)
    result = odd[0:n]

    return result
```

Comment: list(range(1,n*2,2))

Comment: or use *recursion*

Comment: @Frank, this really works, thank you very much. And it looks so simple - but how does it work?

Comment: From 1 to n*2, returns every second number after the first number. Here is the `range()` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy's [arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
import numpy as np
def no_loop_odd_integers(n):
    return np.arange(1,2*n,2).tolist() #.tolist() in the end if want list not np array
```

Or without numpy, use the built-in [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) as suggested in the comments:

```
def no_loop_odd_integers2(n):
    return list(range(1,2*n,2))
```

Or, if you are into tensorflow, can use its [range](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range):

```
import tensorflow as tf
def no_loop_odd_integers3(n):
    # create a tensor, convert it to numpy array, then to list:
    return tf.range(1,2*n,2).numpy().tolist()
```

`no_loop_odd_integers(4)`, `no_loop_odd_integers2(4)`, `no_loop_odd_integers3(4)` all return:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

---

*All of the above methods work in the same spirit: you specify from where you want to start your array (ie 1), then you say up to (not including) which number you want to be the upper limit (you want n odd numbers, so the nth odd number is 2n-1, so you say 2n, so all your numbers will be lower than this), then you specify what steps you want to make between these two limits. You want to make steps of 2 (1,3,5,...), so that is the third argument in the range functions in all namespaces.*

Comment: Thank you. This last method is interesting - can you please explain how it works?

Comment: Yep, see my edited answer... Is it satisfactory now?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list comprehension, but it is also a kind of loop

```
def q2(n):
        return [number for number in range(n) if number%2!=0]
```

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. It is an implicit loop, though, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recursion`,

```
def q2(n):
    result = []
    if n:
        result = result + q2(n - 1)
        result.append(n * 2 - 1)

    return result


result = q2(3)
print(result) # output : [1, 3, 5]
```

[This](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/) is a good resource to start learning recursion.

Comment: Thank you. AT this poit I find it a little hard to settle my mind around recursion - can you maybe recommend a resource where it would be explained in words a layman could understand?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the python built-in `filter` function.

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x%2 != 0, range(10*2)))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the range function:

```
def q2(N): return list(range(1,N*2,2))
```

or recursion:

```
def q2(N,r=1): return [r] if N == 1 else [r] + q2(N-1,r+2)
```

or a list comprehension (but that may be considered a loop):

```
def q2(N): return [2*n+1 for n in range(N)]
```